# What is the smallest unknown natural number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics, math-history, big-list, integers

There are several unknown numbers in mathematics, such as optimal constants in some inequalities.
Often it is enough to some estimates for these numbers from above and below, but finding the exact values is also interesting.
There are situations where such unknown numbers are necessarily natural numbers, for example in Ramsey theory.
For example, we know that there is a smallest integer $n$ such that any graph with $n$ vertices contains a complete or an independent subgraph of 10 vertices, but we don't know the exact value of $n$.

What kinds of unknown small (less than 100, say) integers are there?
What are the smallest unknown constants which are known to be integers?
Or, more rigorously, what is the smallest upper bound for an unknown but definable number that is known to be an integer?

I know that asking for the smallest unknown integer is ill-defined since we do not know the exact values.
The more rigorous version of the question is well-posed, but I do not want to keep anyone from offering interesting examples even if they are clearly not going to win the race for the lowest upper bound.

An answer should contain a definition of an integer quantity (or a family of them) and known lower and upper bounds (both of which should be integers, not infinite).
Conjectures about the actual value are also welcome.
I have given one example below to give an idea of what I'm looking for.

Comment: A related question: [What is the smallest number of 45∘−60∘−75∘ triangles that a square can be divided into?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/44684/166535)

Comment: Will you be satisfied with $\begin{cases} 0 & \text{RH is true}\\ 1 & \text{RH is false}\end{cases}$? You can't go smaller than that, by the way! So it's provably the smallest possible case!

Comment: @AsafKaragila: No. :)

Comment: Aww, spoiled sport.

Comment: The smallest infinitely often occurring prime gap. Most likely that's $2$, but we don't know yet.

Comment: @DanielFischer, a good one! Do you want to expand that into an answer?

Comment: @Daniel: I'm not up to the news, but do we know for certainty that there is such gap?

Comment: @AsafKaragila, such a gap is known to exist and the best unconditional upper bound I know is 246. See http://arxiv.org/abs/1409.8361

Comment: @AsafKaragila: A simple argument for the existence: the sequence is bounded below by 2, so $\liminf$ exists.

Comment: @QuangHoang, it does not follow from those that the lim inf is finite. Consider $p_m=m^2$ instead of primes and you'll see what can go awry.

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta: Ah, right. For a moment I thought I were Zhang.

Comment: @Kimball: Nope. True and false have nothing to do with provability. Those are semantic properties. If RH is true in the standard model (regardless as to what proves it or not), then this number is $0$, and if it is not true then the number is $1$. Of course you can switch the values and then you have to decide which number is smaller, and that is a question of provability (if you can prove that RH is provable or not, then you can prove that one is certainly smaller than the other); but that would miss the larger point that this is a number provably in $\{0,1\}$, but we don't know yet which one

Comment: @AsafKaragila You're right.  I got temporarily mixed up.

Comment: Obviously it's the answer to the question "What is the smallest unknown natural number?" The answer to this question is unknown, by definition, and it is known to be a natural number, also by definition. And while in general, for two unknown numbers you cannot say which one is smaller, for this specific problem we know, again by definition, that it is the smallest.

Comment: RH? "Riemann hypothesis"? Probably so, but is it that much standard notation, that it goes without saying? I had to look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RH to make a guess...

Comment: @RolazaroAzeveires Yes, RH is Riemann's hypothesis. I believe you refer to the comment by Asaf Karagila. The abbreviation RH is quite standard, especially in informal use, but I agree that it could have been explained. (There is no mechanism to suggest edits to comments other than flagging for moderator attention.)

Comment: Yes, that was that, thanks. It is a old-ish question, so I thought of simply dropping the most likely explanation for future readers reference, with no need to notify anyone, and forgot about the automatic notification to you.

Answer (score 126):

The smallest infinitely often occurring prime gap, or

$$\liminf_{n\to\infty}\; (p_{n+1} - p_n)$$

is unknown as of now. Most likely, it is $2$, but the twin prime conjecture has not yet been settled.

Due to the work of [Yitang Zhang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yitang_Zhang) and subsequent improvements by others (notably [James Maynard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Maynard_%28mathematician%29) and [Terence Tao](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Terence_Tao)), we know that some prime gaps occur infinitely often. Zhang proved that gaps not larger than 70 million occur infinitely often, and the improvements lowered the bound to $246$ (perhaps there have been recent further improvements I'm not aware of).

Comment: The improvement from $70{,}000{,}000$ to $246$ is impressive; but the improvement from infinity to $70{,}000{,}000$ is ever so slightly more impressive! :-)

Comment: If [Elliott–Halberstam conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliott%E2%80%93Halberstam_conjecture) is true, the bound can be lowered to $6$ (see [this video](https://youtu.be/pp06oGD4m00?t=7m58s)).

Comment: @GlenO Well that's not really fair. Yitang Zhang's paper set forth a new tool which allowed the problem of the Twin Prime Conjecture to be solved - previously we had no idea how to solve it at all.  That was the focus of his paper, which is why he had the absurdly large starting point of $70,000,000$ (as such papers commonly do). Further decreasing of that bound is all work that only exists thanks to his pioneering.

Comment: @Soke And of course Zhang explicitly says that his goal is not to optimize the bound, just prove finiteness.

Comment: To expound upon @Soke's statement: the work by Maynard and Tao is very philosophically similar to Zhang's from what I have gathered but they have different starting points which allowed the gap to be decreased as substantially as it was.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Such an impressive improvement is not unprecedented. For example there is another upper bound which was reduced from Graham's number to 2↑↑↑6.

Comment: @Soke: I know literally nothing on the subject, but all the impressions I got from reading what knowledgeable people had to say, was that it was a particularly surprising result *because* no new tools were used. Yiitang Zhang just squeezed the known methods down and got this bound.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I guess it comes down to what one defines a new tool. It definitely piggy backed on other work but as far as I am aware the method of finding admissible "prime combs" was completely original.

Comment: To add on to my previous comment, in Y. Zhang's paper he says: "This result [$\liminf \limits_{n \to \infty} (p_{n+1} - p_n) < 7 \times 10^7$] is, of course, not optimal. The condition $k_0 \geq 3.5 \times 10^6$ is also crude and there are certain ways to relax it. To replace [it] by a value as small as possible is an open problem that will not be discussed in this paper."

Comment: @CameronWilliams: Maynard-Tao is not that similar Zhang's work. The key element of Zhang's work was that the level of distribution for Bombieri-Vinogradov could be pushed past the $1/2$ barrier by moving to smooth moduli. This is meat of the paper, and his proof originally required Deligne's theorems from algebraic geometry. From this, and a modification of the Goldston-Pintz-Yildirim argument to smooth moduli, we obtain the result. On the other hand, Maynard-Tao is a reworking of the Selberg sieve with multidimensional sieve weights, and it is this added flexibility that is exploited.

Comment: Since the question was about the _smallest_ unknown integer, please take that number and divide by 2 :-)

Answer (score 73):

The chromatic number $\chi$ of the plane satisfies
$4 \le \chi \le 7$, i.e., $\chi \in \{4,5,6,7\}$.
The problem is known as the [*Hadwiger-Nelson problem*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadwiger%E2%80%93Nelson_problem):

> What is
>   the minimum number of colors needed to color the plane such that no two points separated by a distance of exactly $1$ are assigned the same color?

The coloring below, due to John Isbell, shows that $\chi \le 7$:

---

[image: 7-colors]

         

<sup>(Image from [mathpuzzle.com](http://www.mathpuzzle.com/chrompln.html). 
The circles shown have unit radius.)</sup>

---

And the 4-colorability of the unit-distance graph, the
[*Moser Spindle*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moser_spindle), shows that $\chi \ge 4$:

---

[image: Moser Spindle with 4 colors on nodes]

---

**Update** (*16 Apr 2018*):
Aubrey de Grey constructed a unit-distance graph of $1567$ vertices that has chromatic number $5$. See [this post by Adam Goucher](https://cp4space.wordpress.com/2018/04/15/assorted-news-3/).
This improves on the Moser spindle,
and so now we know that $\chi \ge 5$, i.e., now $\chi \in \{5,6,7\}$.

---

[image: 5colors]

     

<sup>de Grey, Aubrey DNJ. "The chromatic number of the plane is at least $5$." [arXiv:1804.02385](https://arxiv.org/abs/1804.02385) (2018).</sup>

---

Comment: There is evidence the answer depends on the Axiom of Choice: Shelah, Saharon, and Alexander Soifer. "Axiom of choice and chromatic number of the plane." *Journal of Combinatorial Theory*, Series A 103.2 (2003): 387-391.

Comment: That the result depends on the axiom of choice is really surprising to me. Whodathunkit!

Comment: @CameronWilliams We don't know for sure that it depends on it, but it might.

Comment: Cute that [Warring's problem $G(3)$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1318394/237) is also in $\{4,5,6,7\}$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams There is a theorem of Erdős that a certain infinite graph coloring problem is equivalent to the negation of the continuum hypothesis; details are at [What is a simple example of an unprovable statement?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1052299/what-is-a-simple-example-of-an-unprovable-statement/1052384#1052384)

Comment: @JosephO'Rourke: If it depends on it, say if it's true only if choice holds, I suppose that then means the problem is kicked into the realm of non-constructive statements? That would be a bummer.

Comment: De Grey's result has directly refuted the assumption of the "Conditional Theorem" in the epilogue of the Shelah-Soifer paper, and can be interpreted as removing the requirement of the assumption "all sets are Lebesgue measurable" from Falconer's proof that the chromatic number of the plane is $\geq 5$. So de Grey has restored some measure of legitimacy to the viewpoint that the chromatic number of the plane has nothing to do with AC.

Answer (score 41):

How about the concrete problem of understanding how many (non-intersecting) spheres can touch another sphere in low dimensions? This is known as the [kissing number problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kissing_number_problem), and it is open in dimension $5$.

In dimension $2$, the kissing number is $6$, given by the hexagonal tiling of the plane:
[image: dimension2]

In dimension $3$, the kissing number is $12$, which is given by spheres at the vertices of the [icosahedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icosahedron). Note that there is actually so much extra space in dimension $3$ that we can swap any two spheres by continuous movement that leaves all the spheres non-intersecting and touching the central sphere. In dimension $4$ the optimal kissing number configuration has $24$ spheres, given by the vertices of the [$24$-cell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/24-cell).

As for dimension $5$, all that is known is that it is at least $40$ and at most $44$. In fact the only other dimensions for which we know the value of the kissing number problem are $8$ and $24$, and this is due to the extraordinary symmetries of the [$E_8$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E8_lattice) and [Leech](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leech_lattice) lattices.

Answer (score 39):

[Ramsey numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey%27s_theorem#Ramsey_numbers) give the smallest sizes of graphs that ensure that certain kinds of subgroups of a given size can always be found.
More specifically, $R(k,l)$ is the smallest integer such that any graph with at least so many vertices contains a complete subgraph of $k$ vertices or an independent subgraph of $l$ vertices.

Some small values are known, but there are surprisingly small unknown ones.
For example:

- $36\leq R(4,6)\leq41$
- $43\leq R(5,5)\leq48$<sup>1</sup>

*The Electronic Journal of Combinatorics* has a [dynamical survey of small Ramsey numbers](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/DS1) which you can consult for more details and newest bounds.

---

<sup>1</sup>
At the time of writing this answer the limit was $49$.
Vigleik Angeltveit and Brendan D. McKay released a [preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.08768) on March 26, 2017, proving $R(5,5)\leq 48$.
The value has been updated in the dynamical survey as well.
If there are changes to the relevant numbers in the survey, feel free to edit.
(Other sources for updates can also be mentioned, but I will restrict the listed numbers to the values of the survey for consistence.)

Comment: The combinatorial number for which [Graham's number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham%27s_number) is an upper bound may be a good candidate for the smallest unknown number, assuming its true value is close to the lower bound.

Comment: @bof Graham's number is no longer the best upper bound for that problem.

Answer (score 24):

Consider the following problem:

> Find the smallest $n$ such that every number $k\geq3n$ with the same parity as $n$ can be written as the sum of $n$ odd primes.

- $n=1$ is trivially not true, because it states that every odd number is prime.
- For $n=2$ it is the Goldbach Conjecture.
- For $n=3$ it is the Weak Goldbach Conjecture, proven in 2013.

So the answer is in the set $\{2,3\}$.

Answer (score 16):

How big is $2^{\aleph_\omega}$? ($\aleph_\omega$ is the $\omega$th uncountable cardinality.)

Of course, this question is well out of reach of ZFC, and certainly not about finite objects. However, Saharon Shelah showed that we can prove certain restrictions on this (and other) exponential quantities. In particular, he showed $$\text{If $2^{\aleph_k}<\aleph_\omega$ for every $k\in\omega$, then $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{\omega_4}$.}$$

So far as I know the "4" is not known to be optimal, nor is there a good reason to believe it is apart from our inability to do better; see section 2 of Chapter IX of Shelah's book *Cardinal Arithmetic*, colorfully titled "Why the hell is it four?"

So here's an interesting unknown finite number:

> What is the least $n$ such that ZFC proves: if $2^{\aleph_k}<\aleph_\omega$ for all $k\in\omega$, then $2^{\aleph_\omega}<\aleph_{\omega_n}$?

This may seem like a curiosity, but I think that computing this number - in particular, proving optimality, and reducing from 4 to something smaller if that's possible - would require fundamental advances in set theory.

Comment: See also [my answer here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/814110/622).

Comment: This is also an interesting one, because it is from set theory, and not from number theory like most here.

Answer (score 12):

Consider the value $$\max_{x \to \infty} \min \text{collatz}(x) . $$

Here, $\text{collatz}(x)$ for $x \in \mathbb{N}$ is defined as the set of generated numbers in the $3x + 1$-sequence in the [Collatz conjecture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture) when started from $x$.

Collatz conjecture is that $\max _{x \to \infty} \min \text{collatz}(x) = 1$

Comment: The value is conjectured to be 1, but is it known to be finite? If yes, is there a bound?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta If there were a (reasonable) bound, then one could prove Collatz.

Comment: @Kimball, if it's not known to be finite, it's not necessarily a natural number. Therefore it's not exactly in the spirit of the question; if it was known to be a small integer, it would probably soon be known to be one.

Comment: That's a fair point.

Comment: Also, if it's not $1$ it is very large, given the work done on it.

Answer (score 9):

The value of $G(3)$ in the Waring's problem, or the upper bound to the number of cubes that are necessary to write a sufficiently large number.

Progress to this problem:

- Every number that is 4 or 5 mod 9 needs 4 cubes.
- It has been proven that 7 is enough by Linnik (1943).

Therefore $G(3)$ is a value form the set $\{4,5,6,7\}$.

---

Also, another thing related to Waring's problem:

> What are the solutions to
>
> $$2^k\{(3/2)^k\}+\lfloor (3/2)^k \rfloor > 2^k$$

Here $\{\}$ denotes the fractional part. It is conjectured that there are no solutions. It has been proven that there are only finitely many solutions.

Comment: No, $g(3)$ is the upper bound of cubes needed to express an integer. It is known to be 9 (see Wikipedia). E.g. $g(2)=4$ by Lagrange's four-square theorem and the fact that not every integer can be a sum of $2$ or $3$ cubes.

Comment: @user26486 No this is a variant. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Waring's_problem

Comment: Well yes, I should've looked at $G(3)$. But still, $G(3)$ is defined as the upper bound of cubes needed to express a sufficiently large number. Your definition of it is wrong.

Comment: @user26486 fixed

Answer (score 8):

Let me post another example.

> What is the ninth solitary number?

It is known to be in the set $\{10,11\}$.

In fact, it is not know for any $k \geq 9$ what the $k$th solitary number is.

Answer (score 8):

Which one of $\zeta (5),\zeta(7),\zeta(9),\zeta(11)$ is irrational. One of these were proven to be irrational, but it is not known which one out of the 4 are irrational.

Comment: Of course, most likely they are all irrational, but we aren't close to proving that.

Answer (score 7):

The number of Fermat primes $F_n=2^{2^n}+1$.

One can easily check $F_0\to F_4$ are all primes. In history, it was conjectured that all these were prime. However, computational data shows that $F_5\to F_{30}$ are composite. Now it is conjectured that only the first $5$ are prime.

Comment: Is this known to be finite?

Comment: @JiK: Not known.

Answer (score 6):

For any integer $N$, we can ask the following question: what is the smallest integer $k$ such that $\Sigma(k)>N$ (Busy Beaver function)? The answer is unknown for every $N\geq 4098$. For $N=4098$ the answer is either $5$ or $6$, and for, say, Graham's number, the answer is between $5$ and $22$.

Answer (score 6):

Elliptic curves over $\mathbb Q$ of rank at least 28 are known, but their exact rank is not known.

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to unknown numbers that have a known "small" upper bound (e.g. $1$), or are otherwise likely to be small, here's one that is not very big but could (as far as we know) be fairly big, or not so big, or perhaps as small as $1$: $$\inf_{n\in\Bbb N}\left|\sum_{k=1}^{p+n}(-1)^k(p_{k+1}-p_k)\right|,$$where $p_k$ is the $k$th prime and $p=2^{57885161}-1$ is the [largest known prime](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Largest_known_prime_number). (Here $p$ is chosen for ease of statement. Obviously there are numerous variations on this theme.)

Answer (score 0):

The number $\pi$ has a very significant history and could be the ideal object of many problems about the first position in its decimal expansion in which a given property occurs.

In what position do the following properties occur first?

1. two consecutive twin numbers of two digits (six possible couples)
2. the number 5 appears 5 consecutive times
3. the first square of ten digits
4. Nothing is known about which digit appears countless times. However, it is clear that at least one digit does. What is this digit?

Many other similar questions can be formulated. Note that, excepting item 4, it is not obvious that there are corresponding answers but it is obvious also that their probability of existence is nonzero. A way to be sure of the existence of an answer is as follows:

The famous BBP Formula

$$\pi=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\left[\frac{1}{16^k}\left(\frac{4}{8k+1}-\frac{2}{8k+4}-\frac{1}{8k+5}-\frac{1}{8k+6}\right)\right]$$

gives the value of any position in the expansion of $\pi$ so one can look for some interesting property in an advanced position and ask about the minimal position at which this occurs. (It can be the discovered position, of course.)