# Are there any subsets of $\ \mathbb{R}\ $ that have been investigated, but where it was not determined whether the set is countable or uncountable?

Tags: real-numbers

Are there any subsets of $\ \mathbb{R}\ $ that have been investigated, but where it was not determined whether the set is countable or uncountable? In particular, I am thinking of a subset of $\ \mathbb{R}\ $ where some condition was imposed on the decimal expansions of the numbers in the set.

I have seen [this thread](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/814072/are-there-any-infinite-sets-that-are-not-known-to-be-either-countable-or-uncount), but I am not very knowledgeable on cardinals/ordinals. I was looking for a condition on the decimal expansion of the real numbers.

Or is it the case that such a set would translate to an open problem in mathematics / set theory?

Comment: What is the meaning of where it was not determined, are you asking for a set whose Countabilty is an open problem ?

Comment: Essentially yes. But the problem must have arisen from investigating a condition on the decimal expansions of real numbers.